# How to implemenet this interface in c#

Tags: c#, interface

I have this interface (simplified)

```
public interface IImageSourceViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the lines view model.
    /// </summary>
    IObservableCollection<ILine> LinesViewModel { get; set; }

 }
```

and I have this:

```
public class LineViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, ILine
{

}
```

and I implemented the interface as follow (Simplified):

```
public class ImageSourceViewModel : IImageSourceViewModel
{

      public IObservableCollection<LineViewModel> LinesViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

But I am getting error that LinesViewModel  in implementation can not implement LinesViewModel  in interface as it has a different return type.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

Your implementation must match the interface exactly as mentioned in @Neels answer

If you need to change the type of the IObservableCollection then you will need generics.

Something like:

```
public interface IImageSourceViewModel<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : ILine
{
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the lines view model.
/// </summary>
IObservableCollection<T> LinesViewModel { get; set; }

}


public class ImageSourceViewModel : IImageSourceViewModel<LineViewModel>
{

  public IObservableCollection<LineViewModel> LinesViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How to make sure that T is implement ILine? The point is that users of ImageSourceViewModel  knows about IImageSourceViewModel  and ILine, they don't know about the implementation. They need to use the LinesViewModel as a collections of ILine.

Answer (score 1):

by giving LineViewModel as return type because implementation must match the interface as shown below  !!!

```
 public interface IImageSourceViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the lines view model.
    /// </summary>
    IObservableCollection<LineViewModel > LinesViewModel { get; set; }

 }
```

UPDATE :-

As suggested by @Mike you can go for generics to fulfil your expectation that class should not know about LineViewModel:-

```
public interface IImageSourceViewModel<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : ILine
{
/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the lines view model.
/// </summary>
IObservableCollection<T> LinesViewModel { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: But my class (ImageSourceViewModel ) needs that the list be in LineViewModel.  The fact that LineViewModel is a ILine, why am I getting this error?

Comment: But I don't what that interface knows about the LineViewModel, it should know only about the interface ILine.